# Do we have $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\gcd\left(1+n!,1+n^{2}\right)}{n!}\stackrel{?}{=}e$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, number-theory, factorial, gcd-and-lcm

I try to find a balanced exercise on it with Desmos.

It seems we have:

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\gcd\left(1+n!,1+n^{2}\right)}{n!}\overset?=e$$

It seems non trivial as you can remark in replacing the square by a cube.

At first glance we can think it's problem with hidden rearrrangement theorem. Keeping in mind that I try the Riemann theorem on sequence and rearrangemnt without success. I keep in mind also the Wilson's theorem but cannot progress.

Notice I check the result with Wolfram Alpha.

How to (dis)prove it?

Thanks in advance for the help.

Side notes :

It's a strange idea but why calculus couldn't be here I mean ,and I think it's stupid but let's try that :

$$\gcd\left(\operatorname{floor}\left(\sqrt{2\pi n}\left(\frac{n}{e}\right)^{n}\right)+1,n^{2}+1\right)=^?1,n\in N^+$$

I think it's not very useful but why not ? I think that because it's really not the same problem but as Leibniz said knowledge is like path between some islands...

Ps: It's the floor function .

As second notes see also [Bounds on the difference between the polylogarithm with negative base and the gamma function](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4144869/bounds-on-the-difference-between-the-polylogarithm-with-negative-base-and-the-ga)

Edit 04/02/2023

There is also where $x$ is a prime :
$$\gcd(x!-x^x,1+x^2)=1$$

Then I was thinking to Green-Tao theorem but nothing consistent at all.

Edit 01/11/2023 :

We can represent (I suggest to show it) that :

$\exists a,r,n,m,u>0$ such that :

$$n!+1=\lfloor(1-a^r)^{-m}\rfloor=P$$

And :

$$n^2+1=\lfloor(1-a^r)^{-u}\rfloor=Q$$

Then it seems we have if $a$ is irrational and  $P,Q$ have the prime factorization :

$$P=\prod_{i=1}^{v}p^{b_i}_{a_i},Q=\prod_{i=1}^{N}p^{c_i}_{d_i}$$

If so $\exists a_k,b_k,c_k,d_k$ such that $p^{b_k}_{a_k}$ is not in the prime factorization of $Q$ and vice versa .

Remark see https://publications.ias.edu/deligne/paper/357 and [Can we invert these analogous "Dirichlet" series for GCD / LCM convolution?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3169021/can-we-invert-these-analogous-dirichlet-series-for-gcd-lcm-convolution)

Comment: The numerator is $2$ for $n = 1$ and $1$ otherwise, so the sum should be $e$, not $e + 1$. Did you mean for the sum to start at $n = 0$?

Comment: @TravisWillse I make a mistake see https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?key=&i=%5Csum_%7Bn%3D1%7D%5E%7Binfinity%7D%5Cfrac%7B%5Cgcd%5Cleft%281%2Bn%21%2C1%2Bn%5E%7B2%7D%5Cright%29%7D%7Bn%21%7D-e

Comment: The rearrangement theorem only applies to alternating series that do not converge absolutely. Here, we only have positive values.

Comment: @Peter I assume they mean; *because* all values are positive, the series may be rearranged in any way whatsoever with no consequences

Comment: @ErikSatie The computation you do in WA is misleading - note that it parses $\gcd(1+n!,1+n^2)$ as "PolynomialGCD", that is the GCD of the two expressions $1+n!$ and $1+n^2$. I don't know how WA parses it given the former is not a polynomial, but the result it gives is [constant 1](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?key=&i=%5Cgcd%5Cleft%281%2Bn%21%2C1%2Bn%5E%7B2%7D%5Cright%29)

Comment: @Peter Whoops, I guess my calculator couldn't handle the large numbers!

Comment: @Peter It is fairly clear that the gcd is 1 when $n^2+1$ is composite. How do you show this also holds in the prime case?

Comment: @Wojowu Now , as you ask , I realize that I might have been too fast with my conclusion and might have made a mistake. I have to think about it again. I could however find no counterexample with PARI/GP upto $n=3\cdot 10^5$. A good sign !

Comment: @Wojowu Why is it clear in the case that $n^2+1$ is composite ?

Comment: @Peter I don't know if it's really "fairly clear", but basically: let $d_n$ be the $\gcd(\dots)$, and let $k_n$ be such that $n^2+1=k_n d_n$. If $d_n > 1$, then, by virtue of $\gcd(n!,n!+1) = 1$ and $d_n \mid n!+1$, we have: $d_n \geq n+1$, but that means we must have $k_n \leq n$ otherwise we'd get $n^2+1 = k_nd_n \geq (n+1)^2$, contradiction. However, $k_n \mid n^2+1$ and $\gcd(n^2,n^2+1) = 1$, so $\gcd(k_n,n^2)=1$, which gives $\gcd(k_n,n)=1$. We've established that $k_n \leq n$ before, thus this grants $k_n = 1$, and therefore $n^2+1 = d_n$.

Comment: Now, suppose $d_n$ is composite. Then it would have a prime factor $p$ lesser than $\lfloor\sqrt{d_n}\rfloor \leq \lfloor\sqrt{n^2+1}\rfloor = n$. Since $d_n \mid n!+1$, that would imply that $p \mid n!+1$, but $p \leq n$ provides $p \mid n!$, and so $\gcd(p,n!+1) = 1$ due to $\gcd(n!,n!+1) = 1$, contradiction, and thus $d_n$ is always either prime or $1$. Combined with the prior result, we obtain that $n^2+1$ composite implies $d_n = 1$.

Comment: @Peter I'm afraid I had a gap in my argument, it was essentially the same as Bruno's second post but for some reason I inferred the gcd must be 1 from $n^2+1\nmid n!+1$.

Comment: @BrunoB How do you get $k_n=1$ from $k_n\leq n$ and $\gcd(k_n,n)=1$?

Comment: @Wojowu Oh, well, you don't, my bad on that one... Thanks for noticing that gap! Back to the starting point I guess.

Comment: Is it worth to ask an extra question dealing with whether $\gcd(n^2+1,n!+1)$ is true for every integer $n\ge 2$ ? An interesting conjecture , I would say.

Comment: It is true for $n\le 10^6$

Comment: Extended to $2\cdot 10^6$

Comment: The search for random counterexamples did not reveal a result yet either.

Comment: might be useful to look at polynomials $x^2+1$ and $x(x-1)(x-2)\cdot\dots (x-n+1)$ and then show they are relatively prime over appropriate modulos but I am not so sure.

Comment: Some empirical observations: **Most** values of $n$ satisfy \begin{align}\gcd(1+n!,1+n^{2k})&=\begin{cases}2&\quad\text{if $n=1$}\\1&\quad\text{otherwise}\end{cases}\quad\text{for all $k>0$}\\\gcd(1+n!,1+n^3)&=\begin{cases}n+1&\quad\text{if $n+1$ is prime}\\1&\quad\text{otherwise}\end{cases}\end{align} Higher even powers have the occasional miss; e.g. $\gcd(1+8!,1+8^{10})=61$. Higher odd powers display much less consistent behaviour. In PARI/GP, counterexamples for the even powers can be found through `for(k=1,50,for(i=2,400,if(gcd(1+i!,1+i^(2*k))>1,print(i," ",gcd(1+i!,1+i^(2*k))," ",k))))`.

Comment: Note that if $\mathrm{gcd}(1+n!,1+n^2)\neq 1,$ then we must certainly have that $\mathrm{gcd}(1+n!,1+n^2)=p$ where $p$ is both the smallest prime divisor of $1+n!$ and the largest prime divisor of $1+n^2.$  So https://oeis.org/A051301 and https://oeis.org/A014442 might be useful. Notice the first comment in A014442 - that all elements must by Pythagorean primes. You will notice that (small) Pythagorean primes are hard to come by in A051301, and further notice that the $n$ being $1$ less than a Pythagorean prime (Wilson's guarantees $p$ is Pythagorean) are the only $n$ that result in small $p.$

Comment: Search limit extended to $4\cdot 10^6$, no counterexample, but I think there can well be a counterexample. What makes it difficult to find it is that there is at most one prime factor of $n^2+1$ larger than $n$ and this prime factor must divide $n!+1$

Comment: @MandelBroccoli I know why $p$ is prime and is above $n+1$, and thus is the largest prime divisor of $n^2+1$ (since I showed it amidst my failed attempt above), but I don't quite see why it would need to be the smallest prime divisor of $n!+1$? Though maybe it's a simple obvious reasoning that I'm missing, I apologise in advance if that is the case.

Comment: @BrunoB good point. apologies i was not thinking clearly.

Comment: However, you will see that this is still useful since if the smallest prime divisor of $1+n!$ is too large, then we have solved part of the problem already.

Comment: In any case, I believe that the $n$ which are $1$ less than a Pythagorean prime will be hardest to figure out.

Comment: We would need a method to compute $m!\mod n$ efficiently, where $m,n$ are large numbers and $n$ is prime to increase the search limit significantly. In particular, it is interesting whether $n^2+1\mid n!+1$ is possible for integer $n>2$. If $n>4$ is composite we have $n^2\mid n!$, but I could not make use of this to make any progress.

Comment: $\gcd\left(\operatorname{floor}\left(\sqrt{2\pi n}\left(\frac{n}{e}\right)^{n}\right)+1,n^{2}+1\right)=2$ for $n=3$, $11$, $13$, and $15$.

Comment: The idea from your last edit looks overcomplicated and even if the conclusion holds for some $k$ then a priori it can be that $P$ and $Q$ have a common prime divisor distinct from $p_{a_k}$ and $p_{d_k}$.

Comment: @AlexRavsky So we are agree .

Comment: @Peter If $n/2<m<n-1$ then we can compute $(n-m-1)!\pmod n$ and use the fact that by Wilson's Theorem
$$-1\equiv (n-1)! \equiv m!(n-1)...(n-(n-m-1)) \equiv$$ $$ m!(-1)^{n-m-1}(n-m-1)!\pmod n.$$

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/548027/prove-multinomial-coefficient-probability-theory

Answer (score 23):

Here is a reason why this problem would probably be very hard to solve.

Suppose $(n^2 + 1, n! + 1) = d$. Then any prime divisor of $d$ must be a prime greater than $n$, so $d$ must be a prime greater than $n$ and equivalent to $1$ modulo $4$. Thus, we are looking for a prime $p \equiv 1 \bmod{4}$ and an $n < p$ such that $p | n^2 + 1$ and $p | n! + 1$.

Look at this from the perspective of a random $p \equiv 1 \bmod{4}$. It is well known that there exactly two choices for $n$, $a_p$ and $b_p = p - a_p$, such that $p | a_p^2 + 1$. Given this, as far as I can tell, there is nothing definite we can say about $a_p!$ and $b_p!$ modulo $p$, other than the fact that they are not divisible by $p$. Thus, we can heuristically assume they are equally likely to be equidistributed in $(\mathbb{Z} / p\mathbb{Z})^*$ modulo $p$. Therefore, there is about $2 / (p - 1)$ chance that $p$ satisfies the desired relation.

Taking union over $p$, I conclude that in an interval $[A,B]$, roughly
$$\sum_{p \in[A,B], p \equiv 1 \bmod 4} \frac{2}{p - 1}$$
$p$ would satisfy the desired constraint. We know that
$$\sum_{p \in[A,B], p \equiv 1 \bmod 4} \frac{2}{p - 1} \approx (\log\log B - \log\log A).$$
Solving for this greater than $1$(i.e. at least one solution exists), we get
$$B \geq A^e.$$
@Peter has kindly verified that no solution less than $2 \times 10^6$ exists. Thus, if I were to gamble, I would bet that a solution will eventually pop up, but it is around
$$(2 \times 10^6)^e \approx 10^{17}$$
which is far beyond the computational ability of my computer.

A few more words: the reason I believe we can say nothing about $a_p!$ modulo $p$ is because number theorists have not figured out how to deal with factorials beyond Wilson's theorem. For example, seemingly innocent problems like [Brocard's problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brocard%27s_problem) remain wide open.

P.S. If you were to search for primes of the form $p = n^2 + 1$ only, I would bet no solution exists. The reason is that we can show
$$\sum_{p = n^2 + 1, p> 10^6} \frac{2}{p - 1} < \sum_{n = 10^3}^\infty \frac{2}{n^2} \leq 0.01.$$

Comment: There is a clear pattern that only the factorials $4!,5!,7!$ are solutions to the Brocard's problem. However these patterns are usually not considered when discussing Brocard's problem. Of course patterns are not a proof but they may lead to a proof.

Comment: The values of $a_p!$ and $b_p!$ modulo $p$ are related. Namely, by Wilson's theorem, 
$$a_p!b_p!(-1)^{b_p}\equiv a_p! (p-b_p)...(p-1)\equiv a_p(p-1)!\equiv -a_p \equiv b_p\pmod p.$$

Comment: @AlexRavsky Nice observation. But I don't think this breaks the heuristic, as I don't know any reason that make $a_p!$ not behave like random nonzero element modulo $p$.

Comment: @abacaba can we show $x<0,n>2$ the zero of the two function $$f(x)=\frac{1}{(x/(n^2+1))!},g(x)=\frac{1}{(x/(n!+1))!}$$ are not the same ?