# Prove $\gcd(n^2+1,n!+1)=1$ for any $n>1$.

Tags: number-theory

We may consider formulating a proof by contradiction.

Assume $\gcd(n^2+1,n!+1)=p$, then $p|(n^2+1)$ and $p|(n!+1)$.

Hence, we can conclude $n<p<n^2+1$ .

Can we go on from here?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4580215/do-we-have-sum-n-1-infty-frac-gcd-left1n-1n2-rightn-stackrel

Comment: What is the source of this question?

Comment: I guess we can prove it by an easier way.

Comment: You can conclude that any such $p$ is a prime number. If $p=qr$ then it would also be true that $q,r>n$ whence $p>n^2+1$. That may be why you chose $p$ to represent the gcd, but you didn't explicitly point it out.