# Factorial equation and no solution existing :A conjecture

Tags: inequality, examples-counterexamples, factorial, gamma-function

Conjecture :

Let $x<0,n>2$ ,$n$ an integer such that $|x|<(n!+1)(n^2+1)$ then it seems that :

$$1/(x/(n!+1))!-1/(x/(n^2+1))!=0$$

Have no integer solution in $x$ where :

$$x!=\Gamma(x+1)$$

Or :
$$\Gamma(x/(n!+1)+1)=\Gamma(x/(n^2+1)+1)$$

Based on empirical trial it seems true for low $n$ .It generates a lot of almost integer and the calculus of the factorial is delicate for large value .It recall me a bit the LFT by these empirical facts .

Context :

[Do we have $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\gcd\left(1+n!,1+n^{2}\right)}{n!}\stackrel{?}{=}e$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4580215/do-we-have-sum-n-1-infty-frac-gcd-left1n-1n2-rightn-stackrel)

The goal is to show the two arithmetical sequences doesn't match and then conclude for the $\gcd$.As similarities is the Green-Tao theorem.

Some other information :

There exists $x<0$:

$$1/2+1/2×(2-1/x!^{x!})^2-1/2(x!(1-x!))^2-20(x!(1-x!))^4-127(x!(1-x!))^6+\cdots=f(x!)$$

$$f(z)=z^z-z^2(1-z)^2-20z^4(1-z)^4-21z^6(1-z)^6-33z^8(1-z)^8-33z^{10}(1-z)^{10}-66z^{12}(1-z)^{12}-249z^{14}(1-z)^{14}+\cdots$$

Question :

Is there an argument in the sense of the conjecture or a counter-example ?

Comment: This is hard to parse...Isn't your expression of the form $\frac 1A-\frac 1B=0$?  And, if so, isn't that equivalent to $A=B$?  If so, why write it that way?

Comment: Is that a complicated way to write $ \Gamma\left(\dfrac{x}{n!+1} \right)= \Gamma\left(\dfrac{x}{n^2+1} \right)$ ?

Comment: @lulu,MartinR done .thanks for the comment.

Comment: But is there a reason to write it in that convoluted form?  It seems to introduce complexity for no reason.  If there is context behind the form, maybe that context would be helpful.

Comment: *“It recall me a bit the LFT by these empirical facts”* – What does that mean and what is LFT?

Comment: Are [these](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=Solve+Gamma%28x%2F%284%21%2B1%29%29%3DGamma%28x%2F%284%5E2%2B1%29%29) counterexamples?  I'm still puzzled by the question, so I expect I am misreading it.

Comment: @lulu integer solution

Comment: @MartinR Last fermat theorem

Comment: $x$ wasn't specified to be an integer...only $n$ was.  I suggest editing for clarity.  I don't see the connection to Fermat.

Comment: @Lulu done. LFT is just an empirical comparison

Comment: @Lulu see the edit and tell me if you have a counter-example.

Comment: @MartinR you made a mistake .It misses a +1

Comment: Will $\large\color{red}{\text{Desmos_10}}$ be your next username ? Cheers and Happy New Year !

Comment: Démosthène great! Vous en loupé pas une and I appreciate it .Happy new year !

Comment: For a reference see https://arxiv.org/abs/2301.09699